# iOS receiving "data" but not "notification" portion of Firebase notifications

Tags: ios, unity-game-engine, firebase-notifications

I am using Firebase to send notifications for a Unity game.  On iOS, my test devices are receiving the "data" field of the notification (with parameters unique to my game) but not the "notification" field (title+body text for the user).

On Android, notifications work as expected:

- If the app is in the foreground, it receives both "notification" and "data" fields.
- If the app is in the background, the OS displays an alert with the "notification" params.  When I tap the alert, the app opens and receives the "data" params (only).

On iOS:

- If the app is in the foreground, it receives "data" params only.
- If the app is in the background when the notification arrives, nothing happens immediately.  The next time the app regains focus, it receives the "data" params only.
- The OS does not display an alert in any test case.
- The app does not receive the "notification" params in any test case.

I have tested on two different iOS devices (one iPhone running iOS 12.2, one iPad running iOS 11.1).

I have also tried sending text-only notifications using the Firebase Notification Composer.  These notifications arrive on my Android test device, but have no apparent effect when sent to iOS.

I configured my Unity game and Firebase project following the instructions here:
https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/unity/client

Probably not relevant (since the notification composer is also affected), but for sending out notifications I am using this library on my server:
https://github.com/Redth/PushSharp/

Comment: You might want to check on ur setup on the iOS device, ie the APNS key etc. https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/ios/client#prerequisites

Comment: I believe those are all correct.  Plus, if I'd messed up any of those, I doubt the "data" params would be getting through, either.

Comment: Same here... I have been struggling all day...